# Can I check which application opened .zshrc?

Tags: macos, shell, atom-editor

i am on a Macbook pro Big Sur.
Every time I open Atom (file editor) it executes .zshrc file

Can I set a IF statement to execute specific lines if it is opened by new Terminal, or by Atom (or other applications)

thank you

Comment: Is it being executed by a shell that starts Atom, or is Atom starting a shell that reads the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is to check the PPID to see if it is the login. Applications do not have it.
For example:

```
ps auxwww | grep ${PPID} | grep login
RES=$?

if [[ $RES == 0  ]]; then
     <...>
fi
```